Is it possible to remove a EKS Cluster Security Group tag using terraform?
I am trying to bring up EKS cluster using Terraform EKS blueprint and it creates both clsuter and node security groups. As per AWS documentation, EKS creates the SG tag kubernetes.io/cluster by default on both the SGs. I need to remove the tag using the terraform. Is there a way to do it?

Even if you can, it will be temporary - " If you remove the tags, Amazon EKS adds them back to the security group whenever your cluster is updated."

Why would you need to remove the tag? EKS needs this tag to identify and manage the SG.

While creating the cluster, it creates both Cluster and node SG. So both the SGs need to have the tag?

terraform-aws-eks module creates both Cluster and Worker Node security group and since it is EKS created, it is automatically adding the default tag. In our case, we are trying to create ALB and attach it to a service with targetgroup as IP. In doing so, we are allowing a few rules while creating the ALB ingress. While we apply the changes, the TargetBinding is not happening because 2 SGs have the default tag. So we need to remove the tag from the node security group alone

...TargetBinding is not happening because 2 SGs have the default tag - can you tell how are these 2 related, especially why the default tag matters here?

FailedNetworkReconcile 12m         targetGroupBinding expect exactly one securityGroup tagged with kubernetes.io/cluster/<cluster_name> for eni eni-xxxx, got: [sg-xxx sg-xxx] (clusterName: <cluster_name>)
Got this error. Since both Cluster SG and worker node SG are created by EKS, both are having the tags. Since only one SG is required with the tag for targetgroupbinding, it is failing reconcile.

Based on your question and your answers in the comment section, you could be using the previous version (18?) of terraform-aws-eks which has this issue. The redundant tag can be remove:
node_security_group_tags = {
  "kubernetes.io/cluster/${<your cluster name variable>}" = null
}

Here's the in-depth explanation.
